# Simple Math Game?

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I would like to create simple Math quiz. I have a one textview that I display random question with random operator as below code.I would like, user will input their answer to EditText and submit their answer with ImageButton that I called submit answer. My question is, I could not handle to check user answer on Edittext via different method.How can I check user answer that evaluate the answer after submitbutton ?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int number1, number2, result;
public EditText answer;
char operator;
ImageButton submitAnswer;
Random rand = new Random();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Random rnd = new Random();
    number1 = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
    number2 = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
    generateOperator();
    TextView question = findViewById(R.id.questionText);
    question.setText(number1 + " " + operator + " " + number2 + " " + "=" + " " + "?");

}


public int generateOperator() {
    int op = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
    if (op == 1) {
        operator = '+';
        result = number1+number2;
    } else if (op == 2) {
        operator = '-';
        result= number1-number2;
    } else if (op == 3) {
        operator = '*';
        result = number1+number2;
    }
    return operator;

}

public void submitAnswer(View view) {

                submitAnswer = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
                submitAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if ( result == Integer.valueOf(answer.getText().toString())){

                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Correct",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Wrong",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try `answer.getText().toString()` inside your OnClickListener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, edir your `generateOperator()` method to keep answer.

```
public int generateOperator() {
    int op = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
    if (op == 1) {
        operator = '+';
        result = number1 + number2;
    } else if (op == 2) {
        operator = '-';
        result = number1 - number2;
    } else if (op == 3) {
        operator = '*';
        result = number1 * number2;
    }
    return operator;

}
```

And then you can simply compare your result and the user's answer.

```
submitAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(result == Integer.valueOf(answer.getText().toString())){
                //Answer is ok.
            }
            else {
                //Some code...
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did it.. But I got an crash when I use submitbutton.

Comment: Add `Edittext` binding. `answer = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);`